# customized advanced datagrid in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I had 7 columns in an advanced datagrid and have one comboBox with all of the columns names.
The datagrid should show only the columns the use has selected in the comboBox. Does this mean customization of the advanced datagrid columns? If anyone has any samples, please share them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if you have a DataGrid like this

```
<s:DataGrid 
            width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{ac01}" >
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn id="colType" dataField="type" headerText="Type"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="message" headerText="Message" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

You can trigger some event and call this line of code

```
colType.visible = false;
```

Then the column colType will disappear. If you want to show that column again, just assign the true value to its visible property.